# Where was the "beis Ha'Sereifah"?

Tags: yom-kippur, geography, korban, talmud-bavli, masechet-yoma

On daf 68 of Yoma, we learn that the par chotas (chatos bull) and seir Hashem (goat for God) were intertwined and taken by cohanim to the "beis Ha'sereifah", outside the camp, to be burned.  We also learn, later in Yoma, that those who attended the burning could not be present for the Torah reading by the Cohen Gadol, since they took place at the same time. What was the location of the beis Ha'sereifah, in relation to modern day Jerusalem?

Comment: Edward Stopek, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including [our 59 other questions on _korbanos_](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korban).

Answer (score 1):

[M'Zahav U'Mipaz page 415](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48887&st=&pgnum=451&hilite=) brings in the name of Rabbi Yosef Ades Zatzal that the location is what is currently known as Shaar Mandelbaum in the direction of the grave of Shimon HaTzadik